# Tablesorter custom selection print

Tags: printing, tablesorter

I might be on the wrong track, but is there a way to print the table resulted after filtering with tablesorter custom filters available here http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just use the basic page print, it should print the table as you see it on the screen with the filters applied.

If you want all rows showing, then use a print style to reveal all hidden rows:

```
@media print {
  table.tablesorter tbody tr {
    display: table-row !important;
  }
}
```